# How to make wp8 app keep alive

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my app, I'd like to disable the automatically sleep function. I want it keeps alive all the time.

I tried searching it, however couldn't find any answer. (maybe I didn't find the correct keyword).

So, please anyone tell me how to do it. Thank you

Comment: Does this work for you?look for Mick's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339679/disable-screen-from-autolocking-on-windows-phone-7

Comment: @luchosrock thank you. I tried at first, it didn't work. but it's working now.

Comment: would you answer this question yourself?

Comment: @luchosrock I'd like to accept your answer if you don't mind. thank you for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339679/disable-screen-from-autolocking-on-windows-phone-7

this answer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by disabling UserIdleDetection.

Please look into

[UserIdleDetectionMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Idle detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)