# How to disable Auto Locking when our windows phone app is running?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

i am developing a windows phone app in which i fetching some data from service at that moment the device will go to auto lock since it is un - responsive for long time.

so , how can i avoid this auto locking in the windows phone app when some process/fetching/syncing is happening with services.

i am not able test this scenario since i am testing it on an emulator.

1) how to avoid auto locking feature in windows phone app when it is running?
2) What are the various possible ways in which i can do this ?

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339679/disable-screen-from-autolocking-on-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

PhoneApplicationService phoneAppService = PhoneApplicationService.Current;
phoneAppService.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

This will disable auto locking of screen. Let me know if this works.

**Edit:** This code should be added in App.xaml.cs in the constructor for it to work.